# Wrong location of errorbars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot with multiple lines and with stat_summary defining the mean values. When I apply `geom_errorbar()`, some of them are placed with a some distance to mean indications, which means, that some of them are 'flying'. What is happening?

Thanks!

My code:

```
    #First I add another data set with SE, SD and mean.
cdata <- ddply(data2, c("OGTT","Treatment"), summarise,
               N = sum(!is.na(Glucose)),
               mean = mean(Glucose, na.rm=TRUE),
               sd   = sd(Glucose, na.rm=TRUE),
               se   = sd / sqrt(N))


    #Then I merge it with my original data 
totalglu<-merge(data2,cdata)

#Then I make the ggplot
p<-ggplot(data=totalglu, aes(x = factor(OGTT), y = Glucose, group = StudyID, color=StudyID)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(End.start ~Treatment)+ 
  stat_summary(aes(group = Treatment), geom = "point", fun.y = mean, shape = 16, size = 2) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(x = "OGTT time points (min)",y= "Glucose (mmol/l)")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se,ymax=mean+se), width=.1, colour="black")
p
```

[image: My plot with flying errorbars for a some of the points]

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `mean_cl_normal` to make the mean and CI in one shot instead?  Also: can you post the data that are causing the problem (that is, I don't have `data2`, so can't make the plots you have).

Comment: Sorry I missed this before: It appears that the error bars are in the same place in the top and bottom rows of the grid. The most likely cause is that the faceting is working differently in `stat_summary` and `geom_errorbar` (or in the ddply call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are not using `End.start` when calculating the bars, but it is being used by `stat_summary` because of the faceting.

Try:

```
cdata <- ddply(data2, c("OGTT","Treatment","End.start"), summarise,
               N = sum(!is.na(Glucose)),
               mean = mean(Glucose, na.rm=TRUE),
               sd   = sd(Glucose, na.rm=TRUE),
               se   = sd / sqrt(N))


    #Then I merge it with my original data 
totalglu<-merge(data2,cdata)

#Then I make the ggplot
p<-ggplot(data=totalglu, aes(x = factor(OGTT), y = Glucose, group = StudyID, color=StudyID)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(End.start ~Treatment)+ 
  stat_summary(aes(group = Treatment), geom = "point", fun.y = mean, shape = 16, size = 2) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(x = "OGTT time points (min)",y= "Glucose (mmol/l)")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se,ymax=mean+se), width=.1, colour="black")
p
```

Though, without the actual starting data, I am not quite sure what `data2` looks like, or how `ddply` is affecting things. Instead, I might suggest skipping making `cdata` altogether, and just using:

```
ggplot(data=totalglu, aes(x = factor(OGTT), y = Glucose, group = StudyID, color=StudyID)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(End.start ~Treatment)+ 
  stat_summary(aes(group = Treatment), fun.data = mean_cl_normal) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(x = "OGTT time points (min)",y= "Glucose (mmol/l)")
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! :) That was so helpful! As you said, my problem was that I forgot to use End.start when calculating the bars! Problem solved! :) 
Thank you!